# Select specific columns by string label in R frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to exclude the *"fldname"* labeled column from a frame `frm` in R. If we know the index of the column say `i` then we can use the `frm[-i]` to exclude the `i`<sup>th</sup> column. Is there any simple way to do the same by specifying the column label string or list of label strings which i want to exclude?

I worked out a solution (corrected by Fhnuzoag):

<strike>`frm[names (frm)[names (frm) != c("fldname1","fldname2")]]`</strike>

`frm[names (frm)[!names (frm) %in% c("fldname1","fldname2")]]`

get the list of wanted strings and use them as index. Above *"fldname1"* and *"fldname2"* are the unwanted fields.

Is there a simply solution which the language syntax has?

Comment: `!=` doesn't really work that way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use a combination of negation `!` and `%in%`.  For example, using `iris`:

```
x <- iris[, !names(iris) %in% c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")]
str(x)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, no. Usually I do `frm[, setdiff(names(frm), excludelist)]`.